# getISOCountries() method displays only two letters of contry name. Is Get full name of country using this method possible?

Tags: java, locale

I used following code, but it displays only 2 digit of ISO country name. For example, for "INDIA", it only display "IN". Can I show full name as "INDIA" ?

```
String[] loc= Locale.getISOCountries();
for(int a=0;a<loc.length;a++)
{
    System.out.println("ISO Contry "+a+":"+loc[a]);
}
```

I want full name of ISO country. Is it possible to get using this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [**getDisplayCountry()**](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) method.

Example:

```
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String [] argv) {

    Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
    System.out.println(defaultLocale.getDisplayCountry()); // displays United States
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
To get the complete list of full country names, I'm not aware of any methods. Instead what you can do is, download this [**ISO 3166 Codes**](http://userpage.chemie.fu-berlin.de/diverse/doc/ISO_3166.html) which contains the mapping of full country name to 2-letter to two letter ISO 3166 name, use your earlier `getISOCountries` method to get the 2 letter name and use the mapping.

Comment: Yes, thanks for answer. I tried and  getDisplaycountry() method works nincely. But i can get only single Country in ISO countries which is already available in those countries. How to get all countries name?

Answer (score 2):

Here we can get onlyfull name of Locale which are available in `getAvailableLocale()` method.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Locales
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    for(int i = 0; i < locales.length; i++)
    {
      String locale_name = locales[i].getDisplayName();
      System.out.println((i+1)+":"+locale_name);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this code is pretty useful for giving a developer an idea of what's out there Locale-wise, so I tweaked the code a little and ran it through ideone.com. Here's sorted map of language/country pairs http://ideone.com/gPBgV (In case the ideone link dies, I've also created a [pastebin of the output](http://pastebin.com/EVAHfd3d).)

Answer (score 2):

**Don´t need to download any file.**
You can create the Locale object again with the given 2 country letters, so you do it:

```
String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();

    for (String countryCode : locales) {

        Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);

        System.out.println("Country Code = " + obj.getCountry()
            + ", Country Name = " + obj.getDisplayCountry());

    }
```