# Localizing the two-letter ISO country codes?

Tags: android, localization

Localizing country names can be done with `new Locale("", iso).getDisplayName()` but is there a way of localizing ISO codes themselves? In my widget I'm using those to represent various countries. It seems wrong for a language - say, Arabic - to have countries be represented by the two letter ISO code from another alphabet. What are my options here?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: `String iso2 = Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language().substring(0, 2);`?

Comment: That might be the best solution available. The first two letters might not be the best two to represent each country (eg. UN instead of UK) but it's better than no localization

Comment: No, wrong localization is worse than no localization.

Comment: `getISO3Language` gets the **standard** 3 characters ISO country codes. I'm only shortening it to **2** chars (as per your requirement). I.e.: EN instead of ENG, US instead of USA, DE instead of DEU, FR instead of FRA, ES instead of ESP, FI instead of FIN, IT instead of ITA, ...

Comment: @DerGolem, they are *not* names but codes, and it is absurd to shorten 3-letter codes to two letters when there are standard 2-letter codes.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I'm not aware of a `getISO2Language` function... is there any?

Comment: @DerGolem, I don’t know about a functions (I would be surprised if there isn’t one, since 2-letter codes are much more widely used), but there is surely a standard on them: https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/

Comment: getISOCountries() does it iirc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361168/getisocountries-method-displays-only-two-letters-of-contry-name-is-get-full-n

Comment: But `getISOCountries()` and `getISOLanguages()` both return a list of all the 2 letter codes, `not related to the current locale`. Is this you want?

Comment: Well that's why I made the post in the first place :P I was hoping to find a way to localize the two-letter codes. It doesn't seem like there's such a thing as shortened country names though.. at least not a standardized collection I can use across languages.

Comment: I wrote my own massive json file with forward/reverse lookup objects - provides what you are looking for and a lot more. https://github.com/rolinger/iso-country-data-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, ISO country codes are fixed strings of characters. Their very idea is that they are internationalized, independent of language. They provide the basis for transmitting information about a country in a standardized, language-neutral way; this information can then be displayed in a localized format, but localizing the code would fight against its very purpose.

ISO country codes are meant to be used in machine-readable data, in communication between programs and systems. They are not meant to be displayed to users, though for various reasons, they might be seen by them. Localizing them would still be a wrong move; the correct fix is to change the software that passes them through instead of proper localization.

Comment: So.. how exactly do I get these shortened country name equivalents in other languages?

Comment: They are codes, not “shortened country name equivalents”. There is a repository of country *names* you can use. There is no approved repository of abbreviations for country names. So you can choose between using the localized names, or the ISO codes, or some abbreviations that you need to find out on your own. (Most languages probably don’t have abbreviations, except for a few country names. Whatever you use as your own abbreviations will probably be misunderstood or not understood at all by many people.)